# Парсинг вывода команды 'ps aux' посредством Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, парсер

Мне нужно распарсить вывод команды 'ps aux' с помощью модуля subprocess. Написал такой код:

```
import subprocess

def psaux_run():
   execution-results = subprocess.run('ps aux', shell=True)
   print(execution_results.stdout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    psaux_run()
```

Данный код делает только общий вывод всех системных процессов linux, а мне нужна "выборка":

1. Пользователи системы,
2. Процессы по пользователям,
3. Количество запущенных процессов,
4. Используемая память,
5. Процент использования CPU,
6. Процессы, занимающие больше всего памяти,
7. Процессы, занимающие больше всего CPU.

Как мне продолжить код?

Comment: изучить другие команды. Например w или who покажет пользователей, которые "в системе". К слову, Вы даже не делаете парсинг.

Comment: `execution-results = ` - это синтаксически некорректная конструкция, кстати, код не запустится

Comment: @KoVadim, следующим этапом будет открытие (в понимании открытия их существования) системных библиотек и их вызовов?

Comment: Том готовых библиотек